# Google Apps: Block sending/receiving email while preserving archive access

Tags: email, g-suite

We use Google Apps as our email service provider.

I would like to prevent a user from sending or receiving any new mail, while preserving this person's access to the archive of historical messages.

We are not currently using Postini.

**Sending:**  I can't find anything myself.

**Receiving:**  Using Email Delivery, I see that I can turn off all email delivery options so that no messages will be delivered.  It seems, though, that this would fail silently, and I'd prefer to have an auto-responder up or to have the sender get a Not Deliverable notification.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which [edition of Google Apps](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=175121) are you using?

Comment: Education / non-profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to restrict inbound/outbound mail fairly simply.  Under "Manage this domain" create a new organization under "Organization & Users".  Name it "Restricted users" or some such.

[image]

Select the user account(s) you want to restrict.  Select "Move to" and choose your new organization.

[image]

Under "Advanced tools" scroll down to "Restricted email delivery". Add the organization you just created and *do not* add any domains under the "Allowed" list.  Any member of this organization will now be unable to send/receive new mail.

[image]

You can also limit the features of Google Apps (*e.g.* Docs, chat, Picasa, etc) using the same organization.  Here is Google's documentation on the [Restrict email delivery](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=177482) feature.

Comment: Wow, that's great.  I had no idea this was hidden in there.  Bonus:  is it possible to customize the 'email forbidden' email that would get sent, or is it just a default message?

Comment: @Benj I don't believe you can customize the message -- at least I see no way to do this is the Google Apps console.  I suspect something custom would be the purview of Postini's feature set. As an EDU customer you should have a "real" support contact. I would submit the feature request through them.

Comment: makes sense.  FYI, this didn't work until I added at least one domain to the 'allow' list - i used faker.example.com, figuring that no one will really be sending mail to/from that domain...

Comment: @Benj I would have sworn it worked earlier this year with an empty "allowed" list when we tested it. Perhaps something has been "updated"? Thanks for the heads-up regardless.